# NullPointerException for onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I've tried to understand what exactly the Null is saying but on the lines that it says there is an error I've put an array with the correct value. So if anyone can give me a solution would be great.

LogCat:

```
02-29 23:03:52.078: D/Surface(4619): Surface is full screen
02-29 23:03:52.088: D/AndroidRuntime(4619): Shutting down VM
02-29 23:03:52.088: W/dalvikvm(4619): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at com.ratetheplate.application.Reviews$Read.onProgressUpdate(Reviews.java:115)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at com.ratetheplate.application.Reviews$Read.onProgressUpdate(Reviews.java:1)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
02-29 23:03:52.088: E/AndroidRuntime(4619):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Java:

```
package com.ratetheplate.application;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reviews extends Activity {

TextView rssStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
final static String URL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/ratetheplate.tumblr.com/posts.json?api_key=*********************";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.reviews);
    rssStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rss);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("posts");

}

public JSONObject lastPost(String review) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
        return last;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Reviews.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String title, msg;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExectute() {
        title = "Loading";
        msg = "Loading Reviews...";
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Reviews.this);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(msg);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            publishProgress(5);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(88);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        try {
            json = lastPost("posts");
            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
        setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rssStuff.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Reviews.java,see line 115 which line can you tall me ?

Comment: It's the first line under onProgressUpdate,
    dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`.

You are creating a method `onPreExectute()` in which you do the intializing of the `dialog` but that method is neither called explicitly nor by the `AsyncTask`

As a result `dialog` is still `null` when you do `publishProgress`

Change the spelling from `onPreExectute()` to `onPreExecute()` and add `@override` above it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put the ProgressDialog inside Main Activity instead of inside AsyncTask. Then initialize it inside AsyncTask class.
I got this was working for me.
Hope this is gonna work for you to.

Answer (score -1):

I checked you project and changed initialization before onPreExecute as :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(TestProjectActivity.this);
```

It worked for me.